# how to add english and arabic language translators to the website?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a site completely in English!

What I want is to facilitate it with a drop down menu or some link for the Middle East Users to be able to view it in Arabic.

In short I want my website pages to be changed to Arabic when Arabic drop down or some link is clicked.

Comment: Are you trying to incorporate Google's translate tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google and Microsoft both offer widgets you can stick on your website.  (as others have said it's an automatic translations, so you could get some bad results).

- http://translate.google.com/translate_tools
- http://www.microsofttranslator.com/widget/

If you want to pay for real translators; an interesting option: http://amanuens.com/.  You give them access to your source control, and they come in and create all the translation resources for you.

Comment: translate.google.come/translate_tools ..... this seems to be perfect solution for me :) but hv to use it 1st :)

Comment: follow the steps 1, 2, 3 - then paste the resulting javascript into your site.  it's pretty much self explanitory

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing that you should be noted is that Arabic is right-to-left and English is left-to-right. So this makes translation difficult.

First of all you should add `direction="rtl"` to `body` or specific element when you're switching to Arabic. After that you should redefine your CSS with thin new direction. if you had `margin-left:20px` it should be now `margin-right:20px;` so it can be tricky. I have experience in translation into rtl languages and I can say if you want same user experience it's gonna be painful job!

For translation you should have a database of terms in both languages and use JavaScript to injects terms of new language that user selects in that drop-down list into your DOM. most of the time you should have spans with specefic classes or ids to address every term. 
It should work like this:

```
<div id="something" direction="ltr">
    <span class="this-is-a-multilingual-term hello">Hello</span>
</div>
```

javaScript should do this for you:

```
<div id="something" direction="rtl">
    <span class="this-is-a-multilingual-term hello">مرحبا</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Good point. @cheeda: Google Translate will handle the RTL thing for you (to the extent it can, which is a fair bit) if you use their translation widget. If you use their API to translate text fragments, you'll need to set the `direction` attribute yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be automatic (machine translation), you might look at the [Google Translate API](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html). It gives you access to Google's machine translation (the software that handles the http://translate.google.com page).

Note that machine translation isn't brilliant. Although a lot of progress has been made the last few years through the shift to [statistical translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_machine_translation) methods, you can still get some non-sensical results.

Here's an example from that page of using their interface from JavaScript:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Translate API Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="sourceText">Hello world</div>
    <div id="translation"></div>
    <script>
      function translateText(response) { 
        document.getElementById("translation").innerHTML += "<br>" + response.data.translations[0].translatedText;
      }
    </script>
    <script>
      var newScript = document.createElement('script');
      newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
      var sourceText = escape(document.getElementById("sourceText").innerHTML);
      var source = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&source=en&target=de&callback=translateText&q=' + sourceText;
      newScript.src = source;

      // When we add this script to the head, the request is sent off.
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

That example translates one specific part of the page; you'd have to take it from there to translate the entire page.

Comment: or is there any other way through which i can translate my pages into arabic ??

Comment: @cheeda: I've pasted one of the examples into the answer, but you'd want to look through the linked API documentation.

Comment: Error !!! response.data is undefined ..... document.getElementById("trans....data.translations[0].translatedText;

Comment: hey dude u rocks :) thumbs up for u for giving ur precious time to solve other's prob :)

Comment: what if i found both these helpful :s

Comment: @cheeda: In time, you'll have enough reputation to vote answers up (you need a rep of 50 or more, won't take long), and you can vote more than one answer up. (I voted up russau's answer, for instance, because I thought it was helpful.) In terms of which to accept, first off, there's no rush. But once you decide on an approach, if it was one of the approaches here, accept the answer related to it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a decent translation

   - This means getting a native speaker who understands the source language (English) and HTML to translate it
   - If you are thinking about using automated translation software, stop, it is rubbish and will leave people with a bad impression of your site. If someone wants to use automated translation software, then they can find Google Translate or another software package for themselves. (As a rule of thumb, avoid trying to solve Internet wide problems for users, tools they apply everywhere are better then learning a specialist interface for every site)
2. Mirror the site and link to the translated version

   - Your CMS might help with this